# Where to get Sql server 2019 32 bit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am trying to install Sql Server 2019 on my 32 bit windows 10. But I am unable to do so because on the download page of Sql server there is only 64 bit installer available.

Please advise from where can I download 32 bit installer for Sql Server 2019.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't, it doesn't exist. 32-bit versions were [discontinued with SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/discontinued-database-engine-functionality-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#discontinued-features-in--1).

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2014 is the last version available on x86/IA32 architecture

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server